# How to find the word which it had found in string from list of words

Tags: python, regex

How can we know which word is present by using this??

```
word_list = ['hello','hi','super']
if any(word in string for word in word_list):
    print('found')
```

By this I’m able to iterate through the lines, but unable to find which word it had found in that line.

Example:
Consider 4 lines in input

```
Hello samuel\n
Hi how are you\n
I’m super\n
Thanks
```

output expected:

```
Hello,true
Hi,true
Super,true
N/a,false
```

But can someone let me know how to print the word as well which it had found in it.

Comment: Do you care if words are case insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
str = """Hello samuel
Hi how are you
hi I’super
Thankq"""


word_list=["hello","hi","super"]

for line in str.split("\n"):
    word_found = [word.lower() in line.lower() for word in word_list]
    word_filtered = [i for (i, v) in zip(word_list, word_found) if v]
    print("{},{}".format(" ".join(word_filtered) if word_filtered else "n/a", not not word_filtered))
```

Basically what `word in string for word in word_list` of yours does is creating a list `[True, False, False]` depending which line you are currently processing. `any`only checks if any of the element in the list is `True` and returns true.

With this knowledge we can construct something like this.

`word_found = [word.lower() in line.lower() for word in word_list]` this generates the boolean list with `True`if the line contains the word on this position and `False` otherwise. As you see I user lower() to be case insensitive. If this is not what you want please change. But from your output it looks like this is what you want.

`word_filtered = [i for (i, v) in zip(word_list, word_found) if v]` with this I filter out all the words that doesn't exist in the line.

`print("{},{}".format(" ".join(word_filtered) if word_filtered else "n/a", not not word_filtered))` this is to create your expected output.

## Output:

```
hello,True
hi,True
hi super,True
n/a,False
```

As you see I modified your input a bit (see line 3). As you can see this solution prints any word even if there is multiple matches on a line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do:

```
Word_list=['hello','hi','super']

l = ["Hello samuel","Hi how are you","I’super","Thankq"]

for i in l:
    k = [x for x in i.split(' ') if x.lower() in Word_list]
    if k:
        print(f'{k[0]}, true')
    else:
        print(f'N/A, false')

Hello, true
Hi, true
N/A, false
N/A, false
```